# XMl Data into String in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Read the contents of an local XML file in an application and get the whole contents of xml file into a string for blackberry application?

Answer (score 2):

To create a string from a local file see this blackberry forum entry: [Open txt file from mediacard](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Open-txt-file-from-mediacard/m-p/30486#M2297)

Assuming you want to use the data within the XML, I would recommend using a XML parser rather than string manipulation. The following links should get you going with XML parsers and explain some of the trade-offs:

- [Blackberry How To - Use the XML Parser](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800599/How_To_-_Use_the_XML_Parser.html?nodeid=820554&vernum=0)
- [Parsing XML in J2ME](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/parsingxml/)
- [Add XML parsing to your J2ME applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wi-parsexml/)

If, however, you have any say about the format used **JSON** might be a good alternative. JSON is easy for machines to parse (thus using fewer resources) and it's human readable.

Answer (score 0):

I have found using a SAXParser and subclassing DefaultHandler has worked well.  Allows to go element by element.